# Data binding results in [object Object]

Tags: html, .net, angular, typescript, .net-core

I am trying to bind the records of rows to my view. This is my code on the backend:

```
 [Route("GetCarCount")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<long> Count()
        {
            return await _context.Cars.CountAsync();
        }
```

I have test this and it works. I get a result like a number

**9**

Now I want to bind this on the view this is my code in the service.

```
 getCount() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'GetCarCount');
  }
```

And I call this method like this:

```
 GetCarCount() {
    this.countrecords = this.carservice.getCount();
  }
```

I have declared a variable like this:

```
countrecords: any;
```

Now I bind it like this:

```
<label>Records count: = {{countrecords}}</label>
```

It doesn't show the number `9`instead I get `[object Object]`

I have tried like this but it didn't work for me

JSON.parse
JSON.stringify

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from your implementation, `countrecords` will be of type `Observable<number>`. Use the `async` pipe in your template to unwrap its value.

```
<label>Records count: = {{countrecords | async}}</label>
```

Comment: Yes! This is working I didn't knew about the async attribute I am reading now the docs of it. Thanks for your time!

Comment: To give you a GIST: It's a `Pipe` that unwraps the value wrapped by an `Observable` or a `Promise`. It's recommended to use this instead of manually having to `subscribe` and `unsubscribe` `Observable`s and `Subscription`s respectively in TypeScript Classes.

Comment: If this is what you were looking for, please consider marking this answer as a solution to close the loop :)

Answer (score 2):

The *countrecords* varibales will be a observable. 
The http methods like .get or .put are Cold Observables ->

> *Cold observables start running only upon subscription, i.e., the observable sequence only starts pushing values to the observers when
>   Subscribe is called. (…) This is different from hot observables such
>   as mouse move events or stock tickers which are already producing
>   values even before a subscription is active.*

Hence

- It's highly probably that the API request is not being made
- Moreover in the {{countrecords}} it won't show the value that was returned to you since that holds a subscription (and not the value you'll get on subscribing that subscription)

What I would suggest is

```js
GetCarCount() {
this.carservice.getCount().subscribe((value)=>{this.countrecords=value});
}
```

and the rest will remain the same.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation!